# Rails UserMailer send out form parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mailer

I have a form that saves the parameters into a CSV, but I also want to send the parameters within an email, always to the same address. I currently have the following:

**mailer**

```
def notification_email(partner)

  @partner = partner   

  mail(:subject => "Partner Application", :to => "example@example.com")

end
```

**controller**

```
partner = Hash.new

params.each do |k, v|

  partner[k] = v

end

UserMailer.notification_email(@partner).deliver
format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'general', :action => 'partnerApplyThanks'}
format.json { render :json => @partner, :status => :created, :location => @partner }
```

**mailer view**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><%= @partner[:first_name] %></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

But I get this error:

`undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

referring to this part of the mailer view:

```
<td><%= @partner[:first_name] %></td>
```

Comment: `UserMailer.notification_email(partner).deliver`...you assign the hash  in `partner` not `@partner`

Comment: now I get this error instead: `undefined method 'first_name' for #<Hash:0x00000002cdffd0>` for the same part of the mailer

Comment: check you hash(@partner) is it contain any first_name key?

Comment: it should.. the first parameter of `partner` is first_name, then in my mailer i've put `@partner = partner`

Comment: Avoid using real emails on questions, i edited it for you.

Comment: thank you, I completely missed that!

Comment: can you puts <%=@partner%> it doe not contain first_name as an key contain any value so you got or try `@partner["first_name"]` Please let me know

Comment: then I get `too few arguments` on the line `format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'general', :action => 'partnerApplyThanks'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this:

**mailer**

```
def notification_email(params)

@partner = params

mail(:to => "example@example.com", :subject => "Partner Application" )

end
```

**controller**

```
UserMailer.notification_email(params).deliver
```

**mailer view**

```
<td>Forename:</td><td> <%= @partner[:first_name]%></td>
```